# how to checkbox using react-native-select-multiple in a row

Tags: react-native

I'm developing form App and struggling with multiple checkboxes.
How to line up the checkboxes in a row?
I have twenty checkboxes, and I want five of them are in a row, four lines in total.
My code is like this:

```
<SelectMultiple
        items = {some_items}
        selectedItems={this.state.some_items}
        onSelectionsChange={(target) => this.setState({some_items: target})}
        style={styles.multi_checks}
        rowStyle={styles.multi_check}
/>

//these are styles
multi_checks:{
  flexDirection:'row',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
},
multi_check:{
  flex:1,
  width: 100
},
```

All checkbox are in line and there are twenty lines....

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is make a grid layout, but its not provided by the author of react-native-select-multiple. What you need to do is fork the library and try doing it your self or try to achieve similar functionality without using the library.

Comment: That's what I want to know. Thanks.
If you know any library of multiple checkboxes with grid layout, please let me know. I will use it.